# How to get this if-else redirection in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess code in a certain folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I make this so this happens IF the HTTP_REFERER is my own site, but if it's not, then redirect to a certain file?

I've been trying something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*MYSITE.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?id=$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://.*MYSITE.*$ [NC]
    RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ MYFILE.jpg
</IfModule>
```

I've already gone through several posts on this topic but nothing worked the way I want it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
 RewriteEngine on

#if http_referer is not my site then redirect the request 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/thispage\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/thispage.php [L,R=301]
#rules for mysite.com
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem is, when http://example.com/ is an internal page, it enters an infinite loophole of redirections. Any ideas?

Comment: @llMagnus I added a condition to prevent the loop error. Please replace `/thispage.php` with the file where your non-httpReferer urls will go to and clear your browser cache to test this.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you very much, that works perfectly.